# Redis design help (From Relational to NoSQL)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, redis, nosql

I am very much a SQL developer and am new to redis, but it's performance is very interesting. I have a problem I think redis could help me very much in. I have a SQL table familiar to this:

```
| CONTAINER <String><NoUnq> | PROCESS <String><NoUnq> | PROCESS_DATA <String><NoUnq> | TimeCreated <TimeStamp><NoUnq>|
```

This table when populated to its max has roughly ~450,000,000 rows. I am running this on AWS. With these rows I select all the processes within a container (~1,000,000 containers), so I would have something like this in sql (of course container is indexed):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE container = '[CONTAINER_NAME]';
```

I then have a cronjob script which runs every hour and removes old processes from containers with something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE TimeCreated <= [SOME_TIME];
```

So essentially I like to have processes which are not older than ~4-5 hours. Looking at Redis I feel like I can engineer something similar to improve my performance, but am having trouble to convert this SQL like design into Redis.

My first thought was to use HSET, but I found out HSET does not allow the EXPIRE command on fields so I could not automatically remove old process. I am most concerned about performance and efficiency.

Comment: Are you looking the equivalents of both statements (SELECT and DELETE) in Redis?

Comment: Not really equvalent as I thonk that would juat be get and del commands, but what I am looking for is an efficient method to select all keys which have the same container. As well, I would like to delete all keys which are old.

Answer (score 0):

Look's like you can (and probably should) use [HSET](http://redis.io/commands/hset). And look's like you do not need to expire fields. You need to expire keys. The key name based on `container name` and [EXPIREAT](http://redis.io/commands/expireat) on this key. If you told about table relation structure like you wrote above the most like analogue is one table row is one key:

```
MULTI
HMSET <container name:rowId> PROCESS <value> PROCESS_DATA <value>
EXPIREAT <container name:rowId> <TimeCreated>
EXEC
```

Also you can use ZSET to store time related list of rows:

```
ZADD <container name> <TimeCreated> <rowId>
```

So you may use zRange as `SELECT` equivalent. Also you may use LUA scripting to get content of container with one request. Something like (I can make a mistake somewhere in the syntax of LUA):

```
 local result = {}
 local tmp = redis.call( 'zrange', KEYS[1], ARG[1], ARG[2], 'withscores' )
 for k, v in pairs(tmp) do
    result[v] = redis.call('hgetall', KEYS[1] + ':' + k)
 end
 return result
```

Where KEYS[1](http://redis.io/commands/hset) - container name, ARG[1](http://redis.io/commands/hset) - from , ARG[2](http://redis.io/commands/expireat)- to .

p.s. Also you should understand [how redis expire keys](http://redis.io/commands/expire) to understand thats happens with memory at your instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would this then delete the entire container? If so, I cannot have this because there will be other processes in the container that will not be too old so I need them to still be in there.